# Incrementing Number Inside String

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a client's requirement, I have set out several images as follows:

```
img/img1.jpg
img/img2.jpg
img/img3.jpg
...
img/img4.jpg.
```

Now, I need to make the function that loads images dynamic. At the moment, the current solution is as follows:

```
// Grab the last image path

var lastImagePath = $("lastImage").attr("src");

// Increment the value.

var nextImagePath = "img/img" + (+lastImagePath.replace("img/img").replace(".jpg") + 1) + ".jpg";

// So on.
```

I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to increment the number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slightly cleaner:

```
var nextImagePath = lastImagePath.replace(/\d+/, function (n) { return ++n; });
```

This uses the version of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that accepts a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and a function.